# How to combine sequential operations with side effects in TensorFlow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision

I'm developing a GAN in TensorFlow. Currently the training schedule is

```
feed_dict = ...
sess.run(discriminator_train_op, feed_dict);
sess.run(generator_train_op, feed_dict);
sess.run(generator_train_op, feed_dict);
```

We train the generator twice each step because we find that it results in better stability.

Now I want to combine the operations together so I only need to feed the network once, as feeding is slow in Tensorflow. I tried

```
with tf.control_dependencies([discriminator_train_op]):
    train_op = tf.group(generator_train_op);
with tf.control_dependencies([train_op]):
    train_op = tf.group(generator_train_op);
```

Supposedly `control_dependencies` specify one operation must happen after another. But the profiling timeline shows that certain gradient descent done in generator are parallel to those in discriminator. In other words, the order is not enforced. In addition, I find out by adding debug statements in the network that the combined `train_op` trains only the generator once, not twice.

Is there any way that I can move the control of this sequence of operations from Python to Tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

```
with tf.control_dependencies([discriminator_train_op]):
    train_op_g1 = tf.group(generator_train_op);
with tf.control_dependencies([train_op_g1]):
    train_op_g2 = tf.group(generator_train_op);

sess.run([discriminator_train_op, train_op_g1, train_op_g2], feed_dict)
```